# dogded barcharts with ggplot2 and two variables on x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

From this data

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)    
test <- structure(list(Name = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Bob", 
    "Marc", "Tim"), class = "factor"), Group = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", 
    "B", "C"), class = "factor"), X2012 = 11:13, X2013 = c(14L, 15L, 
    15L), X2014 = c(12L, 14L, 13L)), .Names = c("Name", "Group", 
    "X2012", "X2013", "X2014"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -3L))
test.melt <- melt(test)
names(test.melt) <- c("Name", "Group", "Year", "Mean")
```

i want to create a barplot that puts the three factor levels from column "Name" as the main x-axis variable. Each of the three levels (Bob, Marc, Tim) should have three dodged bars (the levels of "Year"), and should be coloured by "Group". Plotted on the y-axis should be the value given in "Mean".
I tried

```
ggplot(test.melt, aes(x=Name, y=value, fill=Group)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

but i dont know how to tell ggplot2 what to dodge, i.e. what to do with "Year". Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Year as a group category somewhere. Here, I used color, but it would also work with shape, but for the latter you don'r see which of the bars corresponds to which year.

```
ggplot(test.melt, aes(x=Name, y=Mean, fill=Group, color=Year)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```